# False URL in wordpress localhost

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working with localwebsite , when I use background-image:url('wp-content/uploads/....')
It renders the link of `localhost/wp-content/uploads/...` instead of `localhost/foldername/wp-content/uploads/...`
Do anyone has an idea ?This is what I have done but none of them has worked.
In .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /foldername/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /foldername/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in wp-config.php

I have added

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/foldername' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/foldername/' );
```

but that doesn't work
DO anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `/` on beggining, so `url('/wp-content/uploads/....')`

Comment: doesn't work also

Comment: what's your homepage url? `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/foldername/`?

Comment: http://localhost/foldername/